# Cannot change page with transition

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, header, navbar, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm working on jquery mobile to design my app.

My design is: In the file Index.html, I have a navbar in the header, each option loading a different external page below the navbar.

In each external page, I will load the list of title for read. When I click each title row of list, it will show the content of the title with transition: "Slide" and still hold the navbar in header.

Can I do that ? I worked in two day and still got no solution.

**main.js + index.html**

```js
var pagesHistory = [];
var currentPage = {};
var path = "";
  
function wlCommonInit(){
 // Common initialization code goes here
 $("#pagePort").load("pages/Page1.html", function(){
  $.getScript(path + "js/Page1.js", function() {
   if (currentPage.init) {
    currentPage.init();
   }
  });
 });
}
   
function loadPage1(){
    $("#pagePort").load("pages/Page1.html");
};
function loadPage2(){
    $("#pagePort").load("pages/Page2.html");
};
function loadPage3(){
    $("#pagePort").load("pages/Page3.html");
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NavBar</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
    <script src="libs/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css"> 
</head>
<body style="display: none;">
    <!--application UI goes here-->
    <article data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#page-1" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" onclick="loadPage1();">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page-2" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" onclick="loadPage2();">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page-3" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" onclick="loadPage3();">Page 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page-1" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" onclick="loadPage1();">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page-2" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" onclick="loadPage2();">Page 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- This is a placeholder for dynamic page content -->
        <div data-role="content" class="ui-content">
            <div id="pagePort"></div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page1.js + Page1.html**

```js
currentPage = {};
currentPage.init = function(){
    WL.Logger.debug("MainPage :: init");
    $("#pagePort").pagecontainer({defaults: true});
};

currentPage.loadPage = function(){
WL.Logger.debug("MainPage :: loadPage 1:: ");
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change","pages/Page2.html", {transition:slide},true,true);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <!--
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
    <script>
    $.getScript(path + "js/Page1.js");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="content" >
        <p id="currentPage">
            Currently <b>Page1.html</b> page is loaded.
            Day la content 1
        </p>
        <input type="button" id="loadPage2Button" class="appButton" value="Load Page2.html" onclick="currentPage.loadPage();" />
        <input type="button" id="loadPageContent" class="appButton" value="Load Content.html" onclick="currentPage.loadPageContent();" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome on SO! Your English is not the issue here. If you read the [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, you'll see you're supposed to provide a code example together with an explanation of the expected result and what is not working. Right now it's almost impossible to understand what the issue is...

Comment: Opp my mistake, thank for your recommend
I updated this post.

Comment: OK now you would need to explain a bit better on what is going wrong, "It doesn't work" is as vague as can be. What is working, what is not ? Maybe put some comment in your code explaining what each thing is intended to do and if it works or not. That's quite some lines of code here, not that well formatted (I will try to edit it), you'll need to help us to understand :-)

Comment: OK. I mean, how can I change page without change navbar with transition : "Slide " 
For example I change Page1.html to Page2.html. I just want to change page without change navbar header. 
 But in my code, when I change page1.html to page2.html with transition:"Slide" It will replace my navbar by header page2.html